# changing elasticsearch default min_term_freq and min_doc_freq

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, drf-haystack

I use this technologies/packages in django for handling search page

- elasticseach 2 (as search database)
- elasticseach-py
- django-haystack (as search tools with elasticseach backend engin)
- drf-haystack (for using django-haystack in django-rest-framework)

where can I change **min_term_freq** and **min_doc_freq** default values

because my **More Like This** search not working

any other suggestions are welcomed